# closing the overlay Div in responsive mode

Tags: html, overlay

I am having a issue in closing the overlay in responsive mode in Firefox browser. to understand better please go to jsfiddle and press add address button, a popup will open.....every thing works fine even close button works fine until you open the popup in responsive mode by pressing ctrl+shift+m and switch back to desktop view while the popup is opened close button stop working.

#### View on <kbd>**[jsfiddle Snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/3aew2cgf/)**</kbd>

#### jQuery code

```
$(".close").click(function(){
    var confirmVal = confirm("Do you really want to remove the default address?");
    
    if(confirmVal) {
        $(this).closest("div").parent().remove();
    } else {
        // cancel button clicked
    }
});
```

Comment: how many people do you think will want to do that on your site (I didn't even know ctrl+shift+m</kbd> existed :)...? just asking... you may be putting too much effort into a probably very minor issue...

Comment: if user rotate his mobile same thing will happen then what?

Comment: please at least add relevant tags (FF, mobile...), your question seems to be a little more localized than how it has been written up...